# How to render 404 page outside main layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router@6`, and want to add a route for 404 pages, and render the page ***outside*** the main layout. This is what I have so far:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
      <Route
        path='/'
        element={<HomePage />}
      />

      <Route
        path='login'
        element={<LoginPage />}
      />
    </Route>
    <Route
      path='*'
      element={<PageNotFound />}
    />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The `"*"` route works fine, `PageNotFound` component is rendering outside the layout, as it should. Problem is that the any of the other routes does not show up, only the layout.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are there any errors? Can you [edit] to share the `Layout` component code for a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese no errors, just the empty layout

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe it sounds like the `Layout` component is missing rendering an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      ... common layout UI ...
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render out here
    </>
  );
};
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path='login' element={<LoginPage />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

For more details you can see the following:

- [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets)

Comment: I took a workaround and managed to render the 404 with some stylling. Don't have access to the code at the moment, but I'll give this a try when I do. `Outlet` is new for me, must try. Thanks :-)